# Unclosed element '<td>' in Ember.js 1.12.0 using if/else conditional helper

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have a newly-added section of code in my Ember.js/Handlebars template that looks like:

```
      {{#each day in week.days}}
        {{#if day.today}}
        <td class="active">
        {{else}}
        <td>
        {{/if}}
          <h5><b>{{day.mileage}}</b></h5>
          <br/>
          {{day.dayStr}}
        </td>
      {{/each}}
```

Where the `day.today` comes from an object populated like:

```
{
    ...
    today: dateEquals(new Date(), currentDate)
}
```

And I would like (in the little calendar I'm drawing) for that date to be highlighted if it's *today*.

But, when attempting to run this, the following error is emitted:

```
[18191:0927/082737:INFO:CONSOLE(12363)] "Uncaught Error: Unclosed element `td` (on line 14).", source: file:///path/to/project/js/libs/ember-template-compiler-1.12.0.js (12363)
```

Is this error coming from the *pre-rendered* template? Surely at runtime ("rendertime") there will only be either `<td>` or `<td class="active">`, but never both.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Ember?

Comment: Currently using v1.12.0

Comment: A sidenote: `{{#each week.days as |day|}}` is the current syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Ember v1.11 you can use [inline-if helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_inline-if) in combination with [bound attribute syntax](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_bound-attribute-syntax):

```
{{#each day in week.days}}
  <td class="{{if day.today 'active'}}">
    <h5><b>{{day.mileage}}</b></h5>
    <br/>
    {{day.dayStr}}
  </td>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this *does* work. But is there a reason why, for more complicated logic in the future, I can't use `if/else` to build my DOM? Are these kind of "unclosed element" errors always going to ignore the template logic?

Comment: I think you could submit issue in ember repo, because what you do should work in my opinion, but - to be honest - you won't encounter an issue where you have to do what you did. I never encountered such issue where I couldn't rewrite my element to inline-if helper. This is issue of HTMLBars probably which performs check.

Comment: Check first if it would work in Ember 1.13 or Ember 2.0, maybe it's solved already.

Comment: This is not quite an issue, HTMLBars simply doesn't know that you close the tag because it's inside another conditional branch. If you want to do if/else, contain the whole tag inside each branch — I believe this leads to less bugs/confusion down the line as well.

Comment: Valuable comment. So it seems like it could be design decision.

Comment: How would you rewrite this one: `{{#if active}}<div class="clickable" {{action 'divClicked'}}>{{else}}<div class="nonclickable>{{/if}}`

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, contain the whole tag inside the conditional branch so HTMLBars can "see" that you close the tag, and not leave it hanging. Like so:

```
{{#each week.days as |day|}}
  {{#if day.today}}
    <td class="active">
      <h5><b>{{day.mileage}}</b></h5>
      <br/>
      {{day.dayStr}}
    </td>
  {{else}}
    <td>
      <h5><b>{{day.mileage}}</b></h5>
      <br/>
      {{day.dayStr}}
    </td>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

This seems like a lot of repetition, but I've found it usually leads to less bugs when modifying the layout down the road. It might also be an indication that you might want to extract it to a component, and either employ the inline-if Daniel mentions in the other answer, or make your own helper.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way, but as you mention, this is way too much repetition.

Comment: That's why I also mentioned extracting the repeating HTML to a component, either way your structure will remain explicit.